# When using cloud foundry to deploy react apps, my users cannot see the changes unless they delete browser data

Tags: reactjs, cloud-foundry

I just released my react app in a production environment in Cloud Foundry, but the only problem is that if I make changes to the app, and reupload the app, my users don't see the changes unless they clear their browser data, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for this issue:** *Browser is using its cache not your build to serve the client*

**Remedy to outcome:** *Inform the changes in metadata.json*
metadata.json is a file that swings between request and browser checks for any mismatch with it's cache. if no then cache is served to client.

There are more then one way, thus am not telling direct solution, instead gothrough the below link will take to through various steps to follow
[flexdinesh blog from dev.to](https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk)

Comment: Then you should probably find to create one, it is a solution